# Does this regular expression generate a regular language?

Tags: regex

I was told that the language generated by the regular expression:

```
(a*b*)*
```

is regular.

However, my thinking goes against this, as follows. Can anyone please provide an explanation whether I'm thinking right or wrong?

*My Thoughts*

`(a*b*)` refers to a single sequence of any amount of `a`, followed by any amount of `b` (can be empty). And this single sequence (which can't be changed) can be repeated 0 or more time. For example:

```
   a* = a  
   b* = bbbb  
-> (a*b*) = abbbb  
-> (a*b*)* = abbbbabbbbabbbb, ...
```

On the other hand, since `aba` is not an exact repetition of the sequence `ab`, it is not included in the language.

```
aaabaaabaaab  => is included in the language  
aba           => is not included in the language
```

Thus, the language consists of sequences that are an arbitrary-time repetition of a subsequence that is any amount of `a` followed by any amount of `b`. Therefore, the language is not regular since it requires a stack.

Comment: I think `aba` is in the language. Because you have zero or more occurrences of either `a` and `b`, zero or more times.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what things like "in language" means, but here's a breakdown of the regex...The `()` essentially group the characters between them, meaning that any operator applied to the `()` will apply to everything inside (and it'll act as a capture group... but that's besides the point). The `*` means "0 or more of these" so essentially, this gets interpreted as any number of a's and any number of b's repeated any number of times in any order. It can be simplified to be `[ab]*` if you don't care about the capture group.

Comment: I think the stack is not necessary. A simple deterministic finite state machine accepting the language can be constructed, so it looks like regular to me.

Comment: I see, thanks for the second opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is not `+`.

`aba` is in that language; it's just an overly-complicated way to say "the set of all strings consisting of `a`s and `b`s".

**EDIT**: The repeating group doesn't mean that the contents of the group must be repeated exactly; that would require a backreference.  (`(a*b*)?\1*`)
Rather, it means that the group itself should be repeated, matching any string that it can match.

Comment: Or not a's and b's. So it will actually match any string?

Comment: @Golez: No; it won't match `c`.

Answer (score 4):

It's `a` zero or more times, followed by `b` zero or more times, repeated zero or more times.

```
""
"a"
"b"
"ab"
"ba"
"aab"
"bbabb"
"aba"
```

all pass.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrong. :)

0 is also an amount, so aba is in this language. It wouldn't be if the regex was (a+b+)+, because + would mean '1 or more' where * means '0 or more'.

Answer (score 0):

Technically /(a*b*)*/ will match everything and nothing.

Because all the operators are *'s it means zero or more. So since zero is an option, it will pretty much match anything.

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong, you don't need a stack. Your DFA just thinks "can I add just another a (or not)?" or "can I add just another b (or not)?" in an endless loop until the word is consumed.

Answer (score 0):

It is a regular expression, yes.

The `*` say something like "can repeat 0 or more times". The `+` is basically similar, different only that it need one repeatition on minimal (or be 1 or more times).

This regular expressions says, somethink like:

- Repeat `"below group"` zero or more times;

  - Repeat `a` zero or more times;
  - Repeat `b` zero or more times;

Can works fine with all of your examples.

**Edit/Note**: the `aba` is validated too.

I hope to help :p

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it'll match any string thats empty or made by a bunch of a and b. It reads:

```
(('a' zero or + times)('b' zero or + times) zero of plus times
```

That's why it matches `aba`:

```
(('a' one time)('b' one time)) one time ((a one time)(b zero time)) one time
```